# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' C# 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have the below property.

```
 public virtual ICollection<BuildAppStat> ParentBuildAppStats { get; set; }
```

I am assigning BuildAppStat object to this property:

```
PageBuildVersion.ParentBuildAppStats = BuildAppStat;
```

However I am getting the below error:

> Error  218 Cannot implicitly convert type '`SitePartBiz.Models.Objects.BuildAppStat`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SitePartBiz.Models.Objects.BuildAppStat>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\d2\SitePart\SitePartBiz\Repository\PageBuildVrsnRepository.cs    94  52  SitePartBiz

can you please advise how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are assigning to `PageBuildVersion.ParentBuildAppStats` must be the collection of type `BuildAppStat`. It can be a `List` or the `ICollection`.

Comment: something like `BuildAppStat.Select(BuildAppStat=>BuildAppStat.Length).ToList();` ??

Comment: what I have understood is BuildAppStat is a class and to convert it to list you will need to do:                                            PageBuildVersion.ParentBuildAppStats = new List<BuildAppStat>{objBuildAppStat};

Comment: BuildAppStat.Select(BuildAppStat => BuildAppStat.Length).ToList(); this errors- buildappstat does not contain definition for Select

Comment: BuildAppStat is a class and hence you cannot enumerate on it.